# How to replace patterns of data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in an Exel 2007 spreadsheet that looks like the following. The first row is the column heading and the second row data(24000 rows).

```
ANGUILLA AUSTRALIA BAHRAIN BERMUDA BRAZIL
AI-S-    AU-S-     BH-S-   BM-B-   BR-S-
```

How do I make every row look like the following(So i am stripping the data in each row to only show B or S)

```
ANGUILLA AUSTRALIA BAHRAIN BERMUDA BRAZIL
   S          S       S       B      S
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data starts in A2:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2))-2)
```

Comment: this is the best answer!!! i am curious how come people don't vote up? Thank You @pete!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple using the find and replace command from the standard menu.

```
Find AI  replace with ""
Find AU  replace with ""
```

...repeat for BH BM BR

```
Find - replace with ""
```

Done in 6 steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MID` like this (assuming the data you want to replace starts on B2:

```
=MID(B2,4,1)
```

On every line, and then just copy, and using `Paste Special`, paste the values.